# Showing element activates animation in css

Tags: html, css

When an elements display goes from none to some other value its animation(if it has any) activates. 
Does anyone know how to prevent this?

Also it would be nice to understand why this happens. Is because the DOM is being reflown?

Here is an example of what I mean for reference:

https://jsfiddle.net/darlyp/2p2q767r/

HTML

```
<div class="red-square"></div>
<br/>
<button id="btn">
  Hide and Show square
</button>
```

CSS

```
.red-square{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  display: inline-block;
  animation: 1s both moveSquare 1;
}
@keyframes moveSquare{
  0%{
    margin-left: 0px;
  }
  50%{
    margin-left: 400px;
  }
  100%{
    margin-left: 0px;
  }
}
```

JS

```
document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener("click", function() {
  var currentDisplay = document.querySelector('.red-square').style.display;
  if (currentDisplay === 'none') {
    document.querySelector('.red-square').style.display = 'inline-block';
  } else {
    document.querySelector('.red-square').style.display = 'none';
  }
})
```

https://jsfiddle.net/darlyp/2p2q767r/

Comment: You mean you don't want to fire the `moveSquare` animation when `display` is set to "inline-block"?

Comment: can you toggle `opacity/height` instead? https://jsfiddle.net/2p2q767r/1/

Comment: @showdev yes that is correct

Comment: @MichaelCoker that solution works thanks

Answer (score 2):

When you display it, you could set the [`animation-play-state`](https://www.w3schools.com/CSSref/css3_pr_animation-play-state.asp) to `paused`.

[JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Chris_Happy/2p2q767r/2/)

```js
document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener("click", function() {
  var currentDisplay = document.querySelector('.red-square').style.display;
  if (currentDisplay === 'none') {
    document.querySelector('.red-square').style.display = 'inline-block';
    document.querySelector('.red-square').style.animationPlayState = 'paused';
  } else {
    document.querySelector('.red-square').style.display = 'none';
  }
})
```

```css
.red-square{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  display: inline-block;
  animation: 1s both moveSquare 1;
}
@keyframes moveSquare{
  0%{
    margin-left: 0px;
  }
  50%{
    margin-left: 400px;
  }
  100%{
    margin-left: 0px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="red-square"></div>
<br/>
<button id="btn">
  Hide and Show square
</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way would be to toggle `opacity` instead, and change the `height` to `0` when it's hidden so it doesn't occupy any space on the page.

```js
document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener("click", function() {
  document.querySelector('.red-square').classList.toggle('hide');
})
```

```css
.red-square {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  display: inline-block;
  animation: 1s both moveSquare 1;
}

@keyframes moveSquare {
  0% {
    margin-left: 0px;
  }
  50% {
    margin-left: 400px;
  }
  100% {
    margin-left: 0px;
  }
}

.hide {
  opacity: 0;
  height: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="red-square"></div>
<br/>
<button id="btn">
  Hide and Show square
</button>
```